# Sorting an array of arrays in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var myArray: [[String]] =
[
    ["1", "picture1.png", "John", "Smith"],
    ["2", "picture2.png", "Mike", "Rutherford"],
]
```

How to sort myArray on first item ? second item ? ascending ? descending ?

Many Thanks

Comment: You would have a much easier time if you use structs or classes to package this related data into self-contained instances.

Comment: It's more recommended to have a `struct` or `class` that represent the info in that array with properties like index (I guess that's what 1 or 2 mean), pictureName, Name, FamilyName rather than using an array of strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you create a `struct` or `class` to package this related data together:

```
struct Person {
    let id: Int
    let picture: String // This should probably be a URL, NSImage or UIImage
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}
```

And then define your instances with the correct types (e.g. the `id` is an `Int`, not a `String` representation of an `Int`.

```
let people = [
    Person(
        id: 1,
        picture: "picture1.png",
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Smith"
    ),
    Person(
        id: 2,
        picture: "picture2.png",
        firstName: "Mike",
        lastName: "Rutherford"
    ),
]
```

From there, you can sort it any which way you please:

```
people.sorted{ $0.id < $1.id }
people.sorted{ $0.id > $1.id }
people.sorted{ $0.picture < $1.picture }
people.sorted{ $0.picture > $1.picture }
people.sorted{ $0.firstName < $1.firstName }
people.sorted{ $0.firstName > $1.firstName }
people.sorted{ $0.lastName < $1.lastName }
people.sorted{ $0.lastName > $1.lastName }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, that index ranged is not checked, what could lead to a fatal error at runtime. Check Alexanders comment! :)

```
var myArray: [[String]] =
[
    ["1", "picture1.png", "John", "Smith"],
    ["2", "picture2.png", "Mike", "Rutherford"],
]

func sort<T: Comparable>(ArrayOfArrays: [[T]], sortingIndex: Int, sortFunc: (T, T) -> Bool)) -> [[T]] {
    return ArrayOfArrays.sorted {sortFunc($0[sortingIndex], $1[sortingIndex])}
    }
}

print(sort(ArrayOfArrays: myArray, sortingIndex: 0, sortFunc: <)) 
//[["1", "picture1.png", "John", "Smith"], ["2", "picture2.png", "Mike", "Rutherford"]]
print(sort(ArrayOfArrays: myArray, sortingIndex: 0, sortFunc: >)) 
//[["2", "picture2.png", "Mike", "Rutherford"], ["1", "picture1.png", "John", "Smith"]]
```

Comment: You don't need all the enum stuff. Just pass a comparison function: https://gist.github.com/PeeJWeeJ/d53b9c07158d92b59ab14512dc2275d0

Comment: Nice thanks! You could just have edited my solution or am I wrong?

Comment: Don't want to start a style war. :-) Plus, mumma always said it was rude to touch other people's functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Thank you to mumma too,

Answer (score 0):

Swift's Array has a built-in sort function. Just call it.

```
myArray[0].sort { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }
myArray[1].sort { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the arrays using numeric string comparison (e.g. where "2" < "10") of the item at a particular `index`:

```
let index = 1  // sort by second entry
myArray.sort { $0[index].compare($1[index], options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }
```

If you don't need numeric comparisons (e.g. where "10" < "2"):

```
myArray.sort { $0[index] < $1[index] }
```

---

As others point out, though, you really should be using arrays of custom `struct` or `class` rather than representing your objects as mere array of strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.